# UIWebview caching to disk

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a simple iOS app that loads and list of links and presents them in a UIWebview. The app, when installed, is ~2MB. After clicking around through some of the links, I noticed that the disk usage of documents and data jumped to over 10MB. As a couple days went on, I noticed the disk usage continued to grow. My question is, what is the best way to manage disk storage on iOS?

The goal of this app is to be very minimal and not heavy on resources, but I'm concerned that it will continue to consume more and more disk space with, what I assume is, cached web content. Should I / is there a way to set a cache size? Or does iOS just handle this for me and delete old data eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not optimize prematurely! Resources on disk put no strain on RAM memory, so don't worry about it. If the system is managing caching for you, it is not up to you to guess what it will do. If it needs to clear space, it will presumably clear space. Don't worry, be happy.

Now, having said, you do get some control over a NSURLRequest caching policy. Look at the NSURLRequest docs to learn more about that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My concern, though, is whether the iOS is going to handle the disk cache properly. I just printed the following, I can't understand why usage > capacity:
 
`(lldb) po (int)[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage]
$0 = 23023616 [no Objective-C description available]
(lldb) p (int)[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] diskCapacity]
(int) $1 = 20971520`

Comment: After some additional testing, it appears that the cache gets pruned after the capacity is exceeded. So it seems normal to go over the capacity and to expect the next time it gets hit, the OS will start removing things. Does that seems correct? If so, then I think you're right and that I don't need to be messing with it.

Comment: That is what an automatically maintained cache *is*. It fills and prunes, fills and prunes. Don't worry, be happy. I think I've already said that. :)

Comment: It is actually kind of cool that you were able to get actual numbers on this, though.

Answer (score 2):

Specify cache size:

```
int cacheSizeMemory = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Remove all stored cached URL responses:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Hope to be useful to you!