# Does WKWebsiteDataStore ever remove cached data on its own?

Tags: ios, caching, wkwebview

When using WKWebView, do you need to actively remove cached data using [WKWebsiteDataStore.removeData(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore/1532936-removedata) or does WKWebsiteDataStore handle this on its own?

**Background**

We have a SwiftUI App displaying lots of web content using WKWebView. We noticed that the app's disk footprint is growing over time (Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage -> App XY). "Documents & Data" will grow from 0MB to over 1GB for certain users.

Most of the footprint is in `/AppData/Library/Caches/WebKit/NetworkCache/Version 16`.

Comment: Possibly related answer (and its comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/16600104/348796